# How to read images from Google Drive

Tags: matlab

I need to read images saved in the Google drive. The URL links to these images are known. How to achieve this? Here is the link to one image: https://drive.google.com/u/1/open?usp=forms_web&id=1zy9oeFqsce4daMybpxULHADmEEfpsEru. I want to read this image to Matlab workspace.

Comment: I agree with the answer below. Possible methods might include webread() and urlread() but they're not very simple to configure.

Answer (score 2):

You will likely have difficulty accessing an image directly unless you can set it as public access. MATLAB will encounter the same issue I encounter when trying to access that image, which is that I require permission to access it.

A solution to this might be to download the image and refer to it locally instead, or set the google drive copy to be public access.

After you ensure that MATLAB can access the image, use the `imread` function, as described in https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html.